# Resizing encrypted LUKS partition using KDE Partition Manager

Tags: partition, kde, luks

I want to reduce the size of my encrypted LUKS partition so that I can increase my swap size.

From reading here, I thought using kpm would be the easiest as gparted does not support encrypted partitions. So I

1. Booted from KDE Neon Live CD
2. Ran KDE Partition Manger
3. Unlocked my LUKS partition
4. Tried to reduce the size. But it doesn't let me reduce it more than 18Mb. If it helps, I do have over 500MB free on that partition.

Am I missing anything? I do have a timeshift backup, so worse case I can re-install my system and set the right partition sizes and restore from my backup. But I'm trying to avoid that.

**Screenshots below**

[image: Unlocked partition]

[image: Can't reduce the size beyond 18Mb]

**Edit:**

```
$ lsblk

sda               8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0 976.6G  0 part  
└─sda2            8:2    0 886.5G  0 part  
zram0           252:0    0    16G  0 disk  [SWAP]
nvme0n1         259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   498M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2     259:2    0     4G  0 part  /recovery
├─nvme0n1p3     259:3    0   923G  0 part  
│ └─cryptdata   253:0    0   923G  0 crypt 
│   └─data-root 253:1    0   923G  0 lvm   /
└─nvme0n1p4     259:4    0     4G  0 part  
  └─cryptswap   253:2    0     4G  0 crypt [SWAP]
nvme1n1         259:5    0 931.5G  0 disk  
├─nvme1n1p1     259:6    0    16M  0 part  
├─nvme1n1p2     259:7    0 930.9G  0 part  
└─nvme1n1p3     259:8    0   610M  0 part
```

```
$ sudo pvs
  PV                    VG   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
  /dev/mapper/cryptdata data lvm2 a--  923.00g    0
```

```
$ sudo vgs
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  data   1   1   0 wz--n- 923.00g    0
```

```
$ sudo lvs
  LV   VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  root data -wi-ao---- 923.00g
```

Comment: It looks like KDE PM is displaying the size of the LVM physical volume. I'm not sure if it's capable of modifying LVMs.

You can mark disks and partitions as LVM physical volumes (PVs). Those can be combined into volume groups (VGs) from which you can create logical volumes (LVs) which interface with your system like a physical disk would. You canthen format the LV as a LUKS device with a filesystem such as ext4.

Going backwards, you would need to shrink your filesystem, freeing up space to shrink your LUKS partition, then shrink your LV. Shrink VG, then PV.

Comment: What is the output of the `lsblk` command?
Output of `pvs`, `vgs`, and `lvs` are also helpful.

Comment: Thank you @meijin3. I've updated the original post with the output of these commands